# Retrieving a JSON from a youtube URL

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, web-scraping

I was looking for a way to get a youtube video duration without using the API. Checking their HTML source, I see there is a javascript var called ytplayer.config (JSON with info about the video). How can I get that JSON to parse in a script?

Thank you

Edit. This is the var

```
ytplayer.config = {
    "assets": {
        "js": "\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/jsbin\/player-es_MX-vfl0Fpy-X\/base.js",
        "css": "\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/cssbin\/www-player-2x-webp-vflCn1Mkc.css"
    },

    ...
    ...

    "args": {
        "vm": "CAEQAA",
        "cl": "115273808",
        "iv_invideo_url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/annotations_invideo?cap_hist=1\u0026video_id=tRY6WtFVtVY",
        "tmi": "1",
        "no_get_video_log": "1",
        "host_language": "es-419",
        "keywords": "Jorge,Lanata,TN,periodismo",
        "author": "Tribuna de Periodistas",

         ...

        "length_seconds": "130",

         ...

    }
};
```

Comment: create a server side application that accepts an address from your web page and loads the given url from youtube. hopefully the config will be in the "base" page. Otherwise you'll have to use something that behaves like a javascript enabled browser on your server side, to load the youtube page that contians the video, and do some clever things to get to the config ... personally, the API sounds a lot easier

Comment: I really, really do not recommend going around Google's API unless your hands are tied. These "undocumented" APIs can change without your knowledge (this has burned me on more than one occasion).

Comment: Maybe you are both right and I should use the API, but I know it has limits per day

Comment: Check out the "Quota usage" section -  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You can do it by two ways:

Using config object:

```
ytplayer.config.args.length_seconds
```

it gives video time in sec, you can then divide by 60 to get time in minutes

Second way , USing jquery:

```
$('.ytp-time-duration').innerHTML
```

The solution above can be used at client side, let me know if you are looking for server side solution

After user enters the URL, send the url to your server .. use any backend language, I am use to python hence telling you with it.

```
import urllib

link = "https:<youtube url>"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
```

myfile has all the html content , u can use any parser to get the value of

> ytp-time-duration

Hope it helps..

Comment: Can you explain little bit more , what you mean by reading it ?

Comment: I am in my own page, the user enters the url in a form, and when processing the form I want to read the time from the source code of that url, either with jquery or PHP. I need to access the variable in a remote page

Comment: Thanks, yes, it helps